# jQuery .click and .html not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to create a game with jQuery, but none of the options after the first choice work

Sorry i don't have a working example

```
--- jQuery ---
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".console").animate({ scrollTop: $(".console").prop("scrollHeight") - $('.console').height() }, 1000);
    $(".controls").html("<a id=\"00001\">left</a> <a id=\"00002\">right</a>");
    $("#00001").click(function() {
        $(".console_top").append("you turned left\n<br />");
        $(".controls").html("<a id=\"00003\">jump</a> <a id=\"00004\">sit</a>");
        $(".console").animate({ scrollTop: $(".console").prop("scrollHeight") - $('.console').height() }, 1000);
    });
    $("#00002").click(function() {
        $(".console_top").append("you turned right\n<br />");
        $(".controls").html("<a id=\"00003\">jump</a> <a id=\"00004\">sit</a>");
        $(".console").animate({ scrollTop: $(".console").prop("scrollHeight") - $('.console').height() }, 1000);
    });
    $("#00003").click(function() {
        $(".console_top").append("you jumped\n<br />");
        $(".controls").html("<a id=\"00003\">jump again</a> <a id=\"00004\">sit</a>");
        $(".console").animate({ scrollTop: $(".console").prop("scrollHeight") -         $('.console').height() }, 1000);
    });
    $("#00004").click(function() {
        $(".console_top").append("you sit\n<br />");
        $(".controls").html("<a id=\"00004\">stay siting</a> <a id=\"00005\">stand up</a>");
        $(".console").animate({ scrollTop: $(".console").prop("scrollHeight") - $('.console').height() }, 1000);
    });
    $("#00005").click(function() {
        $(".console_top").append("you stand up\n<br />");
        $(".controls").html("<a id=\"00006\">Win this game</a> <a id=\"00007\">Lose This Game</a>");
        $(".console").animate({ scrollTop: $(".console").prop("scrollHeight") - $('.console').height() }, 1000);
    });
    $("#00006").click(function() {
        $(".console_top").append("you win\n<br />");
        $(".controls").html("You're still here? It's over! Go home!");
        $(".console").animate({ scrollTop: $(".console").prop("scrollHeight") - $('.console').height() }, 1000);
    });
    $("#00007").click(function() {
        $(".console_top").append("you lost the game\n<br />");
        $(".controls").html("crap now i lost the <a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Game_(mind_game)\">game</a>");
        $(".console").animate({ scrollTop: $(".console").prop("scrollHeight") - $('.console').height() }, 1000);
    });
});


--- html ---
<div class="main">
<!--Game Console-->
<div class="console">
<div class="console_top">
<br />

</div>
<div class="console_bottom">
<br />
<br />
</div>
</div>
<!--END Game Console-->
<!--Game Controls-->
<div class="controls">

</div>
<!--END Game Controls-->
</div>
```

Comment: You may want to rethink setting `id` to numbers, as it violates the HTML spec.

Comment: Should I change it to a class instead of an id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because #00001, #00002 ...etc is added dynamically you need to use the live function.
ex:

> $('#00001').live('click', function() {
>   do your stuff here
>   });

Answer (score 3):

You're calling .click() on elements that don't yet exist. When you call $(selector).click(handler), jQuery only adds the handler to elements matching the selector *that already exist*. You need to add the click handlers to the elements as you create them.

**ed: the other guys are right, live() or delegate() is the right solution to the problem I describe

Answer (score 1):

That's because all the non-left/right options have their click events bound *before* they even exist.  You should use something like:

```
$("#00003").live("click", ...);
$("#00004").live("click", ...);
$("#00005").live("click", ...);
$("#00006").live("click", ...);
```

You can also use [event delegation](http://www.cmlenz.net/archives/2011/06/jquery-event-delegation) if you're worried about performance.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, the problem is that the elements that match `#00001` and so on aren't in the document yet, so when you search the document for them (which is what `$('#0001')` and so on are doing), it finds nothing and does nothing when you try to attach a `click` handler.

The quickest fix is indeed to use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live), and using [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) would be a slight improvement, but the right answer is a radically simpler structure:

```
--- jQuery ---
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".console").animate({ scrollTop: $(".console").prop("scrollHeight") - $('.console').height() }, 1000);
    var left = $("#left"), right = $("#right"), state = 'start', nextAction = {
        start: {
            left: function() {
                nextAction.start.turn("left");
            },
            right: function() {
                nextAction.start.turn("right");
            },
            turn: function(direction) {
                $(".console_top").append("you turned "+direction+"\n<br />");
                left.text("jump");
                right.text("sit");
                state = 'turned';
            }
        },
        turned: {
            left: function() {
                $(".console_top").append("you jumped\n<br />");
                left.text("jump again");
            },
            right: function() {
                $(".console_top").append("you sit\n<br />");
                left.text("stay sitting");
                right.text("stand up");
                state = 'sitting';
            }
        },
        sitting: {
            left: function() {
                nextAction.turned.left();
            },
            right: function() {
                $(".console_top").append("you stand up\n<br />");
                left.text("Win this game");
                right.text("Lose This Game");
                state = 'stoodup';
            }
        },
        stoodup: {
            left: function() {
                $(".console_top").append("you win\n<br />");
                $(".controls").html("You're still here? It's over! Go home!");
            },
            right: function() {
                $(".console_top").append("you lost the game\n<br />");
                $(".controls").html("crap now i lost the <a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Game_(mind_game)\">game</a>");
            }
        }
    };
    $(".console a").click(function() {
        nextAction[state][this.id]();
        $(".console").animate({ scrollTop: $(".console").prop("scrollHeight") - $('.console').height() }, 1000);
    });
});


--- html ---
<div class="main">
<!--Game Console-->
<div class="console">
<div class="console_top">
<br />

</div>
<div class="console_bottom">
<br />
<br />
</div>
</div>
<!--END Game Console-->
<!--Game Controls-->
<div class="controls">
<a id="left">left</a> <a id="right">right</a>
</div>
<!--END Game Controls-->
</div>
```

This is far from optimal, but it's a lot better, hope this helps.